# Responsive styles for IE only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, size, media-queries

This is an easy one, I think:

I know can get a style for IE only using this CSS:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
     .foo { color: green } /* IE10 */
     *::-ms-backdrop, .foo { color: green } /* IE11 */
}
```

and can make a site responsive using media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .foo { color: green }
}
```

How do I write the code to make a style for IE only at a certain screen size? Neither of the following is working for me, IE is just ignoring this style:

```
@media only screen and (-ms-high-contrast:none) and (max-width: 800px)

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) and (max-width: 800px)
```

Thoughts?